# Preprocessor check constexpr const char* function

Tags: c++, constexpr, preprocessor

I am working with a new version of a library that gives its version as a `static constexpr const char*` function. I am toggling between new and old versions while testing and would like to wrap my code which only compiles in version 6.0 inside of a preprocessor check

Below I have a mock of how the library would present the version number and my attempt to detect if it starts with `'6'`:

```
#include <iostream>

// This comes from a library
static constexpr const char* VersionNumber() { return "6.0"; }

// This would be my intended method of detecting the version number
static constexpr bool isVersionSix() { return VersionNumber()[0] == '6'; }

int main() {
    std::cout << "Code for any version\n";

#if isVersionSix()
    std::cout << "Additional code for version 6.0\n";
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately this is a compiler error:

```
foo.cpp:12:17: error: missing binary operator before token "("
 #if isVersionSix()
```

How can I get around this? On a side note, I figured checking for `'6'` instead of `"6.0"` would be easier for SO, if this can be made to compile then making a `constexpr` string compare function should not be a problem

Comment: It's not possible to use the preprocessor to do this, but you do have options (e.g. just use an `if` if the code inside would compile on any version)

Comment: @Justin, Unfortunately the "Additional code for version 6.0" is a requirement for version 6.0 that does not compile in lower versions. Just looking for a way to avoid setting some manual preprocessor condition every time I swap the libraries

Comment: What version of C++ are you using? On C++17 you can use `if constexpr`. Before that you can use SFINAE tricks to create a `do_v6_work` function which is empty before version 6.

Comment: @DanielH, gcc 6.3.1 std=c++1z

Comment: If you can upgrade your compiler to 7.1, then the best answer is to wrap the additional code with `if constexpr (isVersionSix())`. Unfortunately, 6.3 doesn’t support that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I get around this?

**Option 1**

You can test the version at run time and call a suitable function or have a block of code.

```
int main() {
    std::cout << "Code for any version\n";

    if ( isVersionSix() )
    {
       std::cout << "Additional code for version 6.0\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Option 2**

If branching at run time is not option, you can use a function template that is a noop for prior versions and does something with version 6.0.

```
template <bool>
void doSomething()
{
   // Do nothing
}

// Specialization of the function template
template <> void doSomething<true>()
{
   std::cout << "Additional code for version 6.0\n";
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Code for any version\n";

    doSomething<isVersionSix()>();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There will be more options in C++17 and C++20. In C++17, you can use `if constexpr`, although I believe that the condition would need to depend on a template parameter. In C++20, you could overload your functions with `requires(isVersionSix())` and it should work.

Comment: I cannot use the first option because the code does not compile in lower versions and although the second option does work as a wrapper for a single block of code I will likely have dozens of places where I need code to only appear for a specific version number

Comment: @Justin, would you believe it? I am still working with VS2008 :)

Comment: @asimes, in that case you'll have to use the strategy in Option 2 at all the places.

Answer (score 1):

If you can upgrade to GCC 7, you can use `if constexpr`, as below:

```
#include <iostream>

// This comes from a library
static constexpr const char* VersionNumber() { return "6.0"; }

// This would be my intended method of detecting the version number
static constexpr bool isVersionSix() { return VersionNumber()[0] == '6'; }

int main() {
    std::cout << "Code for any version\n";

    if constexpr (isVersionSix()) {
        std::cout << "Additional code for version 6.0\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

([live example](https://godbolt.org/g/osZmiB))

You can tell that it doesn’t even compile the version 6 stuff if you don’t have it, because even on `-O0` it won’t even put the `"Additional code for version 6.0\n"` into the compiled program if you change the version number.

However, in any case, you might want to improve your version checking function. For example, if the library goes to version 7, your code will no longer work; you might want to update to check if the version is greater than 6 instead of equal to six. If you do that, though, be careful that you won’t run into issues on version 10.

Comment: This is exactly what I would have wanted but I cannot upgrade the compiler to 7.1 (at work)

Comment: Now that I am home I have gcc 7.2.0 and I tried this. Lets forget the version number for a second for an example. If I put code that does not compile inside `#if 0` ... `#endif` it of course compiles. However if I put code that does not compile inside `if constexpr (false) {` ... `}` then it does not compile. This relates to my question because when the version number of the library is less than 6.0 the library does not have required methods for version 6.0

Comment: @asimes It depends on the type of "not compile". Looking into it more, the rules are more restrictive than I had thought, so this is less likely to be helpful than I expected. It's still useful for some forms of not compiling, but probably not in the case of a library like this.